# ngFor in ngFor in select ?

Tags: angular

```
   <li *ngFor="let billingAccount of customerGeneralInfo?.groupedByTechnology">
       <tr *ngFor="let billingaccount of billingAccount.billingAccounts">
        <td>{{billingaccount?.id}}</td>
       </tr>
  </li>
```

I want to display this `billingaccount?.id` in `select`. Any suggestion?

Comment: You want to just show a select with all billingaccount.id options or You want to select with groups of parent and child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that billingAccounts is of type BillingAccounts, 
Try if this works:

```
<li *ngFor="let billingAccount of customerGeneralInfo?.groupedByTechnology">
       <select [(ngModel)]="billingAccount.BillingAccounts">
        <option *ngFor="#billingaccount of billingAccount" [value]="billingaccount.id">{{billingaccount.id}}</option>
       </select>
  </li>
```

Comment: This is the solution, but I just want to add that @Parijat assumed the value of the `[(ngModel)]`, you should put any variable that will hold the selected option here.

Comment: Thanks for correcting that. (y)
I came back on the post to edit those things and, voila..! :D